# Is there an \intertext equivalent for IEEEeqnarray?

Tags: math-mode, equations, ieeetran

I mostly use `align*` environments throughout my document and make heavy use of the `\intertext` macro, but was dismayed to find no such thing exists for `IEEEeqnarray`. I searched the webs (e.g. [How To Typeset Equations in LaTeX](http://moser-isi.ethz.ch/docs/typeset_equations.pdf)), but there seems to be no official documentation on this environment. The IEEEtrantools doc links to itself on this matter.

How can I have an `\intertext`-like line in between equations?

Comment: Use `align` from amsmath/mathtools anyway

Comment: @percusse is amsmath even allowed in those IEEE classes?

Comment: @percusse I don't understand your comment. Are you saying I should ditch `IEEEeqnarray` in favour of `align`. I am not using an `IEEE` class, just the `IEEEtrantools`.

Comment: yep ditching would be the best as for my own taste they don't even make sense in IEEEtran class.

Comment: @daleif yes I use them without any problems.

Comment: Could you explain _why_ you have to use `IEEEeqnarray` rather than `align`, _etc._, from `amsmath`? As it stands, that would eb the answer many people would go for.

Comment: @JosephWright The column specifiers and for the reasons given in "[The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e](http://mirror.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf#page=76)" (type `texdoc lshort`) - Mainly for reasons when one equation line does not fit and needs to be broken into multiple lines. See `3.5.1 Problems with traditional commands`. Also, I found the `IEEEeqnarraybox` to be very useful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just make `\intertext` known to the `IEEEeqnarray` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@IEEEeqnarray}{\relax}{\relax\intertext@}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
    a + b &=& c \\
    b - c &=& a \\
\intertext{\lipsum*[3]}
    a + b + c &=& i \\
\intertext{Even more text}
    a + b + c &=& i
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: there's not much `\intertext` does other than suspending an alignment for typesetting a paragraph. The only thing to do is enabling this meaning, which `amsmath` does for its alignment environments, also for `IEEEeqnarray`; this is achieved by executing `\intertext@` at a suitable spot.

Comment: This is fantastic! You'll have to wait 11 hours till I can award you your bounty.

Comment: actually, `\shortintertext` (from `mathtools`) would look better here, but making that available might be more complicated.

Comment: @barbarabeeton To the contrary, `\shortintertext` needs nothing special, besides doing `\usepackage{mathtools}`.